# php exec unable to fork() warning

Tags: php, exec, limit, fork

Inside a long running php process on a debian system, there is an `exec` statement that gets called thousands of times (~100000 times). The script does batch processing on images, 20 at a time. Part of this, it uses `exec` to call the imagemagick library's `convert` command line utility to extent an image.

The issue is that, after running for few hours and processing few tens of thousands of images, the program starts to fall through a while loop.. because exec can't fork a process, and the entire process quickly comes to a end with a lot of the images still in the processing queue.

I've looked around for the possible causes of exec can't fork warning, and can cross out these possibilities:

1. permissions - I have `777 -R` given to folders related to the process.
2. resource unavailability - Network, Memory, CPU usage, Disk Free Space all seem fine.

It might be due to php's child process limit `php -r "echo exec('ulimit -u');"` getting consumed completely, but I am not sure.

So, how do I run a command line utility, wait for it to complete, make sure every resource the utility used is freed?

Comment: Any reason you cannot use PHP's ImageMagick library instead of using CLI functions via `exec()` calls?

Comment: That's interesting question.. so I do something like this: `convert -gravity center -extent 200x200`. I've looked at imagemagick docs and couldn't figure how to do this.. there is the [extentImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.extentimage.php), [setGravity](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setgravity.php) and [setImageExtent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimageextent.php). I guess I have to use both setGravity and setImageExtent together.